# Regex - expression needs to ignore strings without specific pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search for all instances of a semi-colon and space inside curly brackets. I almost have the expression built, but I'm running into a problem where it is not stopping at the first instance of a closing curly bracket.

Here is the expression:

```
\{.*;.*\}
```

Here are my sample lines:

```
LWD{ARC,STETH,SONSCOPE,ADN}
LWD{GR; RES,PWD}
13-3/8 @ 8010; LOT 11.1; LWD{GR,RES,AIT,DEN,NEUT; GR,DSI} @ 8800; NO SWC; RNG CSG
LWD{GR,RES,DEN,NEUT} @ 10400; NO SWC; LWD{GR,RES} @ 12075; NO SWC; 13-5/8 @ 11998; WOC
```

I need the regex to find lines 2 and 3 but ignore lines 1 and 4.

The script works correctly for the first 3 lines, but it also captures line 4, which does not have a semi-colon inside a curly bracket.

What am I missing? I know it has something to do with the greediness, but I haven't found a way to stop it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a match in both lines, you can use:

```
\{[^{}]*; [^{}]*}
```

- `\{` Match opening curly
- `[^{}]*` Optionally match any char except `{` and `}`
- `;`  Match a semicolon and space
- `[^{}]*` Optionally match any char except `{` and `}`
- `}` Match closing curly

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HTZJVG/1)

Comment: Why does the opening curly need to be escaped ?

Comment: That worked!. I was missing the stuff in the square brackets. Thanks! I'm pretty sure I would not have come up with that.